MS SSAS named instance doesn't work after NTLM deny
Named instance MS SSAS don't accept connections after NTLM incoming/outgoing traffic deny.
There is SPN for this server like:
FQDN SPN: Setspn -s MSOLAPSvc.3/AW-SRV01.AdventureWorks.com:AW-FINANCE AdventureWorks\SSAS-Service 
NetBIOS SPN: Setspn -s MSOLAPSvc.3/AW-SRV01:AW-FINANCE AdventureWorks\SSAS-Service

Also default instance on the same server works correct without any problems. SPN was added same way:
Setspn -s MSOLAPSvc.3/AW-SRV01.AdventureWorks.com AdventureWorks\SSAS-Service


What is the error message you are receiving?

TITLE: Connect to Server
Cannot connect to server_name\instance_name.

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
A connection cannot be made. Ensure that the server is running. (Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient)

Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. (System)

An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host (System)
BUTTONS:
OK
